# Instance Variable without instance constructor in scala?

Tags: scala

I'm a bit confused to [this code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/graphx/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/graphx/EdgeTriplet.scala):

```scala
class EdgeTriplet[VD, ED] extends Edge[ED] {
  
  var srcAttr: VD = _ // nullValue[VD]

  var dstAttr: VD = _ // nullValue[VD]
```

It has two variables (`srcAttr, dstAttr`)

My first doubt is, are these instance variables or something else ?

If they are instance variables, where its constructor available to initialize these variables ?

Please share to understand this

Thanks

Comment: The body of a class is its constructor, so they re being initialized to `_` which is just sugar syntax for probably `null` as Silvio explains in detail in his answer.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, so _ refer to current instance ? for ex this in java ?

Comment: No, to refer to the current instance you use `this` just like in **Java** _(there are other ways but let's not dwell on that)_. - Again, you can just replace that `_` with `null`, as simple as that. As Silvio said, it is just obfuscate syntax that some people use to reduce a little bit of boilerplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Scala's *default initializer* syntax. If an instance variable is initialized with the special underscore `_` constant, it initializes the field to whatever it would be by default if you didn't define any constructors in Java, so things that are reference types on the JVM become `null` and things that are value types become their default value (`0`, `0.0`, `'\0'`, `false`, etc.)

For example,

```
case class SomeClass()

class Example {
  val someInt: Int = _ // Becomes 0
  val someLong: Long = _ // Becomes 0L
  val someBool: Boolean = _ // Becomes false
  val someDouble: Double = _ // Becomes 0.0
  val someString: String = _ // Becomes null
  val someClassInstance: SomeClass = _ // Becomes null
}
```

Assuming `VD` is a class, not just a type alias to some primitive type, it's equivalent to `null`. Honestly, I avoid this syntax like the plague; it's weird and un-intuitive, and most people have to look up what it means.

You can see *all* of the different uses of an underscore in Scala [on this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala). This includes the *default initializer* syntax as well as all of the other places an underscore has meaning in the language.

Comment: can you please share any small example about Scala's default initializer ?

Comment: @Maria I've added some example code to the post. Does that clarify it for you? If not, please let me know how I can make this clear :)

Comment: thanks for sharing, so you mean, even if VD is not part of any constructor of Class, but once Instance is created, VD will be associated as instance variable to instance...is it correct ?

Comment: @Maria Actually, there is a constructor. Scala's constructor syntax is a bit funny if you're used to Java (and it took me awhile to get used to it as well). Every non-abstract class you write in Scala gets a primary constructor by default, and that constructor is the body of the class. So your `EdgeTriplet` has a zero-argument constructor whose body is actually the class body. That `_` initialization is happening inside of your constructor, even though it doesn't necessarily look like it at a glance.